# EXTJS Tabs Icon Size 32x32

Tags: extjs, tabs, icons

i m using this CSS to setting my tab's height

```
.MainPanel .x-tab-bar-strip {
    top: 40px !important; /* Default value is 20, we add 20 = 40 */
}

.MainPanel .x-tab-bar .x-tab-bar-body {
    height: 43px !important; /* Default value is 23, we add 20 = 43 */
    border: 0 !important; /* Overides the border that appears on resizing the grid */
}

.MainPanel .x-tab-bar .x-tab-bar-body .x-box-inner {
    height: 41px !important; /* Default value is 21, we add 20 = 41 */
}

.MainPanel .x-tab-bar .x-tab-bar-body .x-box-inner .x-tab {
    height: 41px !important; /* Default value is 21, we add 20 = 41 */
}

.MainPanel .x-tab-bar .x-tab-bar-body .x-box-inner .x-tab button {
    height: 33px !important; /* Default value 13, we add 20 = 33 */
    line-height: 33px !important; /* Default value 13, we add 20 = 33 */
}
```

The problem is the Icon do not show properly.

[image]

### Question

**I want to change the tabs icon size to 32x32 and align middle.**

Answer (score 0):

Try redefining this class :

```
*.MainPanel .x-tab-icon-el img{
    width: 100%; /* did this to center the icons */ 
    height: 100%; /* did this to center the icons */ 
    display: block; /* did this to center the icons */ 
    margin-left: auto; /* did this to center the icons */ 
    margin-right: auto;    /* did this to center the icons */ 
}*
```

and if needed the rest of the tab content

```
*.MainPanel .x-tab-inner .x-tab-inner-center{
}*
```

Comment: This might be a dumb question. does all the nested <span> elements that make up the tab+icon+label need to be styled to have any effect? and which configuration do you add to the Ext.Create(...) to include these styles?